# Error: could not find function "read_html"

Tags: r, rvest

I use this code

```
library(rvest)
url<-read_html("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team")
```

And I take back this error

```
Error: could not find function "read_html"
```

Any idea what's going wrong with this?

Also in case of multiple links like this

```
library(rvest)
urls<-html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis",
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection",
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%9308"
)
```

I receive this:

```
 Error: is.config(config) is not TRUE
```

How can I make it to work? How is it if I have this links into a txt file?

Comment: The function used to be called `html()`. You're probably using a version of `rvest` where that version of the function name still exists. Try `html()` instead.

Comment: You need to use tools like `lapply` to parse multiple urls. : `lapply(urls, function(j),html(j))`.

Answer (score 19):

The documentation probably referred to the `read_html()` function in the `xml2` package which is written by the same author, Hadley Wickham, after the initial publication of the `rvest` package.

Therefore, you will have to install and load the `xml2` package as follows:

```
install.packages('xml2')
library('xml2')

url<-read_html("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_national_football_team")
```